# Fetching a Call Instance with Twilio (Node Helper Library 3.x)

Tags: json, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

[Twilio is deprecating Node Helper Library 2.x on 8/31/2017](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) and has made some changes with their 3.x version. I used to get the details of a single call with:

```
client.calls(sid).get(function(err, call) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log(call);
    }
});
```

With [2.x](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call?code-sample=code-retrieve-call-by-id-example&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=2.x), the `get()` method returned valid JSON:

`{"sid": "xxxx", "date_created": "xxxx", "date_updated": "xxxx",...`

With [3.x](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call?code-sample=code-retrieve-call-by-id-example&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x), the `fetch()` method replaces `get()` (and promises are now used). With `fetch()`, rather than receive a valid JSON response, I'm now getting a JavaScript `CallInstance` object:

```
CallInstance {
  _version:
   V2010 {
     _domain:
      Api {
        twilio: [Object],
        baseUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com',
        _v2010: [Circular] },
     _version: '2010-04-01',
     _accounts: undefined,
     _account:
      AccountContext {
        _version: [Circular],
        _solution: [Object],
        ...
```

If I piece together the `baseUrl` plus the `uri` from the `CallInstance` (https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxx/Calls/xxx.json), then I can get the old JSON response that I'm looking for.

**Question:** Is there a way for the Twilio Node Helper Library 3.x to return the old, valid JSON format instead of a `CallInstance` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The version 3 [Twilio Node library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) doesn't return a plain JavaScript object and as far as I can see, [looking through the code](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/lib/rest/api/v2010/account/call.js), you can't simply access the plain JSON response from the API using the library.

You could create the URLs yourself and make the request to the API to return the raw response, with something like this (using the same [request library](https://github.com/request/request) that Twilio uses under the hood):

```
var request = require('request');

var accountSid = YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID;
var authToken = YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN;

var callSid = CALL_SID;

var url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+ accountSid +'/Calls/'+ callSid +'.json';

request.get(url, {
  'auth': {
    'user': accountSid,
    'pass': authToken,
    'sendImmediately': true
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

As an aside, I'd like to understand what you need the raw JavaScript object for? All the same data is provided in the `CallInstance` object as well as further methods for loading more or related data about the instance.

Comment: Don't know about the OP, but my reason to want the raw object is because the objects exposed by the library are not JSON-serializable.

Comment: That's fair, though it would be trivial to write a function to extract the data from the library object that you need and serialize it yourself.

Comment: Except I want exactly the object Twilio is returning, not have to reconstruct it from the exposed objects.

Comment: Then making the API calls yourself is probably the best thing for you to do in this case.